# Testing a new challenge v1

Tags: discussion, sandbox

I will use this to test a modified version of [Red vs. Blue - Pixel Team Battlebots](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48353/red-vs-blue-pixel-team-battlebots) code that automaticaly gets data via javascript.

Please ignore it for now.

Answer (score 1):

aa

```
var bot = {
    name: "testBot2",
    numbOfBullets: 7,
    reloadSpeed: 1,
    shotsPerTurn: 1,
    moveSpeed: 2
}
return bot
```

!

```
var shots = []
var testBot_moveUp = true
if(Math.random() * 2 > 1)
    testBot_moveUp = false
shots.push(2)
var move = 0
if (testBot_moveUp)
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] + 2
else
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] - 2
move = 12
var play = []
play.shots = shots
play.move = move
play.reload = false
return play
```

testing code2

Answer (score 0):

```
var bot = {
    name: "testBot",
    numbOfBullets: 7,
    reloadSpeed: 1,
    shotsPerTurn: 1,
    moveSpeed: 2
}
return bot
```

!

```
var shots = []
var testBot_moveUp = true
if(Math.random() * 2 > 1)
    testBot_moveUp = false
shots.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1))
var move = 0
if (testBot_moveUp)
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] + 2
else
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] - 2
move = 12
var play = []
play.shots = shots
play.move = move
play.reload = false
return play
```

testing code

Answer (score 0):

aa

```
var bot = {
    name: "testBot3",
    numbOfBullets: 7,
    reloadSpeed: 1,
    shotsPerTurn: 1,
    moveSpeed: 2
}
return bot
```

!

```
var shots = []
var testBot_moveUp = true
if(Math.random() * 2 > 1)
    testBot_moveUp = false
shots.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 24) + 1));
var move = 0
if (testBot_moveUp)
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] + 2
else
    move = yourMovement[yourMovement.length - 1] - 2
var play = []
play.shots = shots
play.move = move
play.reload = false
return play
```

testing code333